# Jquery - boxes do not animate in IE8 and Below

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, scroll, jquery-animate, scrolltop

I've recently included jQuery to my website to animate two boxes, depending on how far down the page the user scrolls.

They both appear from the top of the page, so are not visible when the page initially loads up (Negative margin-top number).

The code is below, but you can also see a [JSFiddle of it here](http://jsfiddle.net/HLRSR/).

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var away = false;

    $(document).scroll(function() {
        if ($(document).scrollTop() > 150) {
            if (!away) {
                away = true;
                $('#red-box').stop().animate({
                    'margin-top': '0px'
                }, 500);
            }
        } else {
            away = false;
            $('#red-box').stop().animate({
                'margin-top': '-30px'
            }, 150);
        }
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    var away = false;

    $(document).scroll(function() {
        if ($(document).scrollTop() > 250) {
            if (!away) {
                away = true;
                $('#blue-box').stop().animate({
                    'margin-top': '30px'
                }, 500);
            }
        } else {
            away = false;
            $('#blue-box').stop().animate({
                'margin-top': '-200px'
            }, 150);
        }
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="red-box"></div>
<div id="blue-box"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    height:2000px;
}

#red-box {
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    height:30px;
    margin-top:-30px;
    background-color:red;
    z-index:2;
}

#blue-box {
    position:fixed;
    width:150px;
    height:200px;
    margin-left:60px;
    margin-top:-200px;
    background-color:blue;
    z-index:1;
}
```

This seems to work great on all latest versions of all the browsers, but it doesn't work at all on IE8 and below (no real surprise there). The boxes do not animate when the user scrolls and so never appear on the screen.

Could anyone help me to get this to work on IE8? and possibly even IE7?

Comment: Can you be sure to include the relevant code in your question, as well as linking to JsFiddle? Questions should stand alone from other resources. In particular, the folks @ JsFiddle have a hard time keeping it up for long periods of time...

Comment: Ah sorry, I'll be sure to do that in future. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, this is happening because stupid IE didn't have scroll function on **document** object instead it has scroll function on **window** object.

Here is the updated js functions that works for IE and others (although not optimized)

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var away = false;

    $(document).scroll(function() {
        if ($(document).scrollTop() > 150) {
            if (!away) {
                away = true;
                $('#red-box').stop().animate({
                    'margin-top': '0px'
                }, 500);
            }
        } else {
            away = false;
            $('#red-box').stop().animate({
                'margin-top': '-30px'
            }, 150);
        }
    });
});


$(document).ready(function() {
    var away = false;

    $(document).scroll(function() {
        if ($(document).scrollTop() > 250) {
            if (!away) {
                away = true;
                $('#blue-box').stop().animate({
                    'margin-top': '30px'
                }, 500);
            }
        } else {
            away = false;
            $('#blue-box').stop().animate({
                'margin-top': '-200px'
            }, 150);
        }
    });
});

if ($.browser.msie){
$(document).ready(function() {
    var away = false;

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(document).scrollTop() > 150) {
            if (!away) {
                away = true;
                $('#red-box').stop().animate({
                    'margin-top': '0px'
                }, 500);
            }
        } else {
            away = false;
            $('#red-box').stop().animate({
                'margin-top': '-30px'
            }, 150);
        }
    });
});


$(document).ready(function() {
    var away = false;

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(document).scrollTop() > 250) {
            if (!away) {
                away = true;
                $('#blue-box').stop().animate({
                    'margin-top': '30px'
                }, 500);
            }
        } else {
            away = false;
            $('#blue-box').stop().animate({
                'margin-top': '-200px'
            }, 150);
        }
    });
  });
}
```

Here is [link to updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gagan/CDxhb/) .